# MongoDB crashes Express after query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an angularjs dashboard where the user is supposed to fill in a form (giving an ID and a date) and then this data is sent to an express/nodejs server that does a query to a mongodb.

My problem is that if the user fills in an ID that doesn't exist in the database, mongodb will return an error *"cannot read property count of undefined"* and the express server will crash.

I have tried handling the error with a try/catch but nothing changes.

```
try {
            collection
            .aggregate(
              [{$match: {"content.MemberID_Hash": "xxx", "content.Swipe_DateTime": {$regex:"201602"}}},
              {$group: {_id: null, count:{$sum: 1}}}],
              function(err,result) {
                  console.log("User's number of swipes from last month: ", result[0].count);
                  //findUserRank(result[0].count);
                  //getNeighbouringValues(result[0].count);
              });
        } catch (err) {console.log("Wrong query"); console.error(err);}
```

Is there a way I can just return an error while keeping the server running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous , so try /catch will not work  . Programming error need to be validated before use  . result[0] is trying to access even though it does not exist

```
 collection.aggregate(
                  [{$match: {"content.MemberID_Hash": "xxx", "content.Swipe_DateTime": {$regex:"201602"}}},
                  {$group: {_id: null, count:{$sum: 1}}}],
                  function(err,result) {
                      if(err){
                        throw err ;
                      }
                      if(result && result[0]){
                            console.log("User's number of swipes from last month: ", result[0].count);
                           //findUserRank(result[0].count);
                           //getNeighbouringValues(result[0].count);
                      }

                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this error, you must redirect your output in a temporary collection, with tag `$out`

as follow:

```
{$out: "temporaryCollection"}
```

The `temporaryCollection` will be created on your database

[**Here**](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) you can find a `MongoDB` documentation about `$out`

Answer (score 1):

```
        collection
        .aggregate(
          [{$match: {"content.MemberID_Hash": "xxx", "content.Swipe_DateTime": {$regex:"201602"}}},
          {$group: {_id: null, count:{$sum: 1}}}],
          function(err,result) {
              if(err){
                 console.log(err);
                 return;
               }
              else{
              console.log("User's number of swipes from last month: ", result[0].count);
             }
              //findUserRank(result[0].count);
              //getNeighbouringValues(result[0].count);
          });
```

try this if it solves your error.

Comment: Yeah!!! you're right. I forgot to remove them!!! your answer is absolutely right. Go with sumeet!!!